# Using text field value in SQL query without it being submitted

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Application Express (Apex) and basically my situation is: I have 2 items, one is a text field and the other is a hidden item whose value is retrieved by querying a table using a DB link.

What should happen is the user enters a number into the text field, then that number is used in the query for the hidden item to find the row that has a ID that matches the number that the user entered. The value of the hidden item is then set to the contents of one of the columns for that row.

Only issue is, this is all on one page and must be done without submitting the page, so when the user enters the number into the text field, how can I store that number as the value for that item so that it can be used in the query to compute the value of the hidden item?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Apex? Dynamic actions can do this in Apex 4.0 onwards.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Apex 4.2, I'll have a look at dynamic actions, if you know how I can do it using Dynamic actions let me know, thanks

Comment: You create a dynamic action that fires on the Change event on the text field item. The True action would be a PL/SQL block which can retrieve the value for the hidden item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function ajax(user_number) {
                var xmlhttp;
                // get the ID field for easy access... 
                var index =  document.getElementById("index");
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        // here you get back a response... xmlhttp.responseText
                        // set the hidden field with new data.
                        index.value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                // here you make a request to your script to check your database...
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "app/search/?number=" + user_number + '&index=' + index.value, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            function check(user_number) {
                // make some validation here...
                if (user_number.length > 3) {
                    ajax(user_number);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>please enter your secret number</p>
        <!-- the hidden field holding the ID -->
        <input type="hidden" id="index" name="index" value="334" />
        <!-- the search text box where user type his own NUMBER onkeyup it make a request -->
        <input type="text" id="user-number" name="user-number" onkeyup="check(this.value);"/>

    </body>
</html>
```